# Do I have to recheck my luggage and obtain a transfer visa for my connecting flight in Germany?

Tags: air-travel, germany, india, us-citizens

I am traveling from the United States to India via a connecting flight in Munich, Germany (I am a US citizen). Will I have to re-check my luggage and go through TSA, or will it automatically be transferred onto my flight to my final destination ? I have read that if I have to recheck my luggage that I may need to obtain a transit visa.

Comment: US citizens do not require a visa for short stays in the Schengen Area.

Comment: TSA does not operate airport security outside of the US.

Answer (score 3):

**Single Ticket:** If your flights are on a single booking, your bags get will get checked through to the final destination. You just need to walk off the arriving plane and walk over to your departure gate. If this is a Lufthansa Ticket, you most likely arrive and depart both in Concourse L.

**Two Tickets:** If your flights are on separate bookings, you will have to clear immigration, claim your bags, exit landside, go to the check-in counter of your departing airline, drop of your bag and grab a boarding pass, go through security again (it's only called TSA in the US) and exit immigration, and then, finally, go to your gate.

> I have read that if I have to recheck my luggage that I may need to obtain a transit visa.

No. US citizens don't need a Visa for Schengen entry (in most cases) and you are not entering Germany in the first place

Comment: For completeness, would you clear up the visa issue? What the OP had heard does not apply to US citizens, that condition needs to be spelled out for other readers.

Comment: It's possible that baggage here might be transferred from the arriving to the departing flights, if the airlines are affiliated with the same alliance (e.g., Star, One World, etc.) or have an interlining agreement. The OP will have to ask the first-flight airline directly, either before departure or at check-in.

Comment: If the OP's luggage can be checked through (i.e., transferred behind the scenes from the arriving aircraft to the departing aircraft), then the OP should be able to transit without entering Germany, and, therefore, without a visa regardless of citizenship.

Comment: In some cases, not US citizens but others, a visa is needed even when not entering the country.